# Installing Chuck, problem with alsa / JACK / pulse/

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, jack

I typed "make", output was

```
[chuck build]: please use one of the following configurations:
   make linux-alsa, make linux-jack, make linux-pulse,
   make osx, make osx-ub, make cygwin, or make win32
```

First, how to choose among those?

I tried all, here are the errors

make linux-alsa

```
g++ -I. -Ilo -O3 -D__LINUX_ALSA__ -D__PLATFORM_LINUX__ -O3 -fno-strict-aliasing -D__CK_SNDFILE_NATIVE__  -c RtAudio/RtAudio.cpp -o RtAudio/RtAudio.o
RtAudio/RtAudio.cpp:5267:28: fatal error: alsa/asoundlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
makefile:153: recipe for target 'RtAudio/RtAudio.o' failed
make: *** [RtAudio/RtAudio.o] Error 1
```

make linux-pulse

```
g++ -I. -Ilo -O3 -D__LINUX_PULSE__ -D__PLATFORM_LINUX__ -O3 -fno-strict-aliasing -D__CK_SNDFILE_NATIVE__  -c RtAudio/RtAudio.cpp -o RtAudio/RtAudio.o
RtAudio/RtAudio.cpp:6540:25: fatal error: pulse/error.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pulse/error.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
makefile:153: recipe for target 'RtAudio/RtAudio.o' failed
make: *** [RtAudio/RtAudio.o] Error 1
```

make linux-jack

```
RtAudio/RtAudio.cpp:1910:23: fatal error: jack/jack.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jack/jack.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
makefile:153: recipe for target 'RtAudio/RtAudio.o' failed
make: *** [RtAudio/RtAudio.o] Error 1
```

How to solve this? What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely that you don't have the relevant development libraries installed on your machine.

You will need to either consult the software's build documentation (such as a `README` or `INSTALL` file in the software archive's root directory) for a list of dependencies, or figure it out yourself - for the latter, the `apt-file` utility is helpful e.g.

```
$ apt-file search 'alsa/asoundlib.h'
libasound2-dev: /usr/include/alsa/asoundlib.h
libdssialsacompat-dev: /usr/include/dssi/alsa/asoundlib.h
```

suggesting you would need to install the `libasound2-dev` package for example.

The `apt-file` package should be available from the `universe` repository.